# Postgres db replication works. But not in real time in a program interface

Tags: postgresql, triggers, replication

I have been able to make a postgresql replication between two of my local computers, mainly following this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HkgYdirSdi0 with some little changes, by modificating the files `pg_hba.conf` and `postgresql.conf` of both computers.

Then, in the first computer, there is a database that is being filled automatically, and we can see this in a program interface. And in the second computer, there is also this program interface, and the replicated database is linked to it.

My problem is that the second computer shows the new updates of the replicated database only after restarting the interface program. If I do not restart it, it stays freeze (the database is really changing, so the replication works, but it is not being showed actualized automatically in the program interface, unless I restart this program).

What can I do? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is this "interface program"? What does it do?

Comment: It's a complex one made by my company. But I do not think that the problem cames from the program, because in the main computer, the program can read the database changes automatically, and the interface is updated without needing a reload.

Comment: Do you see the replicated data when you query the slave directly, e.g. using `psql`? If yes, the problem is with that "interface program" and there is nothing we can do until you show us the code that "freezes".

Comment: So you do not think that it could be a problem with any kind of trigger or anything? I have been reading and testing with triggers or rules, but I have still not been able to arrive to the point I need.
Also, the code is not freezing. The only thing is that the own interface is not showing the updates of the database, so nothing new appear in the interface program, like if it were freeze.

Comment: Again: check the data directly in the slave through some SQL client (e.g. `psql`) that't the only way to check if the data was properly replicated.

Comment: In fact, when the program is connected in this second computer with another database (not replicated), if we create a simulation, the new rows appear in the database and we can see them in the interface. So the second computer works similar to the first one, but after making the replication, I do not know why it is asynchronous

Comment: Yes, sorry for not answering before. The replicated data is there after using psql.

Comment: Then it's a problem with your "interface program", there is nothing we can do here.

Comment: But the program is working correctly when it is working with a database that is not replicated and that is getting information automatically. The problem cames after the replication, and I do not know why. Maybe it's something about triggers, but I do not know enought about them, even if I have already tried.

Comment: You'll have to debug the program. Triggers seems an unlikely cause, more likely the program wants to write and cannot.

Comment: When I use in psql the command "select * from pg_stat_replication;", I see my replication there, so I suppose that the publication and the subscription worked.

But in the info that this command shows, in the part of "sync_state", it shows "async". Maybe should I change it (still do not know how, I'm checking if "alter publication", or "alter subscription"... not sure yet) to sync to make it work in real time?